# Font size will change during focus using css?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

When I am focusing on link a elements then the only font size is not changing bt I want to change the font size whenever I focus on link a elements of html code...

CSS:

```
a:focus {
  outline-color: ;
  background-color: aqua;
  font-size: 27px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">h</a></li>
  <li><a href="">m</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are aware that focus would tabbing around through form elements. Are you sure you don't want to use `:hover` or `:active`?

Comment: Can you clarify in what circumstances the font size needs to change exactly? As you can see by the answers, that is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is problem? When I replicate youre code its work just fine. Try adding '#'(dummy-link) to links href attribute

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul> 

a:focus
    {
        outline-color: none;
        background-color: aqua;
        font-size: 27px;

    }
```

Comment: Here is on CodePen, dont know how to insert it in answer.   https://codepen.io/petarr/pen/JpxGQq

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use hover or active. The outline color with nothing might also be causing a syntax error.

Hover changes the element when you are over it. Active changes it when it is the current element that is about to be activated.

```
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: aqua;
    font-size: 27px;
    }
```

Comment: `a:focus` and `a:active` appear to be equivalent. If I test with the OP's example, when I click (but don't release the click), the `:focus` style rules get applied. But yes, `:active` and `:focus` would be the more correct pseudo-class.

Comment: This seems to cover all the scenarios: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active